# If a table has many columns, how to write a clearer script?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

I use the following code to create a table which has more than 100 columns.

```py
t = table(1000:0, `TradeDate`TradeTime`SecurityID`TradePrice`TradeVolume`TradeBSFlag……, [DATE, TIME, SYMBOL,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,SYMBOL……])
```

It is inconvenient to confirm the corresponding relation between the name column and the type column.
Is there any other better method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write like this:

```py
schemaTable=table(
array(SYMBOL,0) as  symbol, array(SYMBOL,0) as  market, 
array(DATE,0) as  date, 
array(TIME,0) as  time, 
array(DOUBLE,0) as  preClose,
array(DOUBLE,0) as  open,
array(DOUBLE,0) as  high,
array(DOUBLE,0) as  low,
array(DOUBLE,0) as  last,
array(INT,0) as  numTrades,
array(INT,0) as  curNumTrades,
array(INT,0) as  volume,
array(INT,0) as  curVol,
array(DOUBLE,0) as  turnover,
array(INT,0) as  curTurnover,
array(INT,0) as  peratio1,
array(INT,0) as  peratio2,
array(INT,0) as  totalAskVolume,
array(DOUBLE,0) as  wavgAskPrice,
array(INT,0) as  askLevel,
array(INT,0) as  totalBidVolume,
array(DOUBLE,0) as  wavgBidPrice,
array(INT,0) as  bidLevel,
array(DOUBLE,0) as  iopv,
array(INT,0) as  ytm
)
```